# Lisp - checking if a list is sorted

Tags: sorting, comparison, lisp

I am trying to write a Lisp function ordered that returns True if the list it is given is sorted either in ascending or descending order.

So far I have 3 helper functions to sort either way, then one to compare them  and then finally the function to determine if they are sorted.

I am having trouble when I call compare in my ordered (L) function.  It seems to be destroying the list each time.   Maybe my whole implementation is wrong.  Thanks for looking!

```
(defun ascending (L)
   (sort L #'<)
)

(defun descending (L)
    (sort L #'>)
)

(defun compare (original sorted)
    (cond 
        ; I made this return the opposite for 
        ; easier usage in the condition of ordered
        ((equal original sorted) T) 
    )
)

(defun ordered (L) 
    ;(cond 
    (print L)
    (setq temp1 L)

    (compare L (ascending temp1))
    (print temp1)

    (print L)
    ;)
)
```

Comment: tip: you don't have to create a sorted version of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` is a destructive operation. You probably want something like this, for `ascending`:

```
(defun ascending (L)
  (sort (copy-list L) #'<))
```

And something similar for `descending`, of course. Note the last sentence in this tutorial page: http://www.n-a-n-o.com/lisp/cmucl-tutorials/LISP-tutorial-22.html

Comment: OK that worked perfect, now I am having trouble in my condition statement.   I know it's wrong, just not how to fix it.   If the list is ascending it returns true, but if its descending it returns false.  How can I make it return true for both ascending and descending?

'code'(defun ascending (L)
 (sort (copy-list L) #'<)
)

(defun descending (L)
 (sort (copy-list L) #'>)
)

(defun ordered (L) 
 (cond 
  (T (equal L (ascending L)))
  (T (equal L (descending L)))
 )
)'code'

Comment: Also... I'm using the 'code' tags like it says... what am I doing wrong that it's not formatting it?

Comment: `(defun ordered (L) (or (equal L (ascending L)) (equal L (descending L))))` (use the backtick `)

Comment: Thanks trptcolin, that did it!

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to sort the list.

You just need to look at each pair of consecutive elements and see if they are either all ascending or descending.

For a simple three-liner, you need the operators [`or`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_or.htm), [`every`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm), [`>=`, `<=`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm), and [`rest`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rest.htm).  Remember that a list is just a chain of cons cells, `rest` just provides a reference to the second cell, and that `every` can take several lists as arguments.  You can then translate the problem description quite directly into Lisp code.

Comment: Bordering on being a spoiler, but Svante's hint is right on: That's all you need to implement the desired functionality.

Comment: With the standard <, <=, => and > comparisons, it's enough to do something like `(defun sorted (list predicate) (apply predicate list))`.

Comment: @Vatine:  `apply` is subject to `call-arguments-limit`.  You should not rely on `apply` working with arbitrarily long lists as spreadable argument list.

Comment: True. It'd probably be possible to cook something up that intelligently splits the list or something that cleevrly abuses REDUCE (probably with a small application of LABELS and RETURN-FROM).

Comment: @Vatine:  all you need for your `sortedp` is `every` and `rest`.  :)

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
(defun ordered (list)
  (apply #'< list))
```

You can make it more generic by adding a key parameter:

```
(defun ordered (list &key (test #'<))
  (apply test list))
```

Answer (score 2):

- why do you need COMPARE, when all it does is calling EQUAL with the same arguments?
- TEMP1 is a undeclared variable. Where does it come from?
- SORT is destructive. You need to copy the list first.

Use a Lisp reference like the Hyperspec and/or the Common Lisp Quick Reference.
Also there are some basic introductory books for Lisp, like [Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/).